# convert text file to Excel sheet using SSDT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have requirement where I need to convert text file to Excel Sheet using SSDT.

I have idea how to do like I 
**Step 1.** have to upload data to sql server any table 
and then **Step 2.** from Sql Server to Excel Spread sheet.

But I would like to do it in only one step that is Convert Directly from Text file to Excel Sheet without sending it to the table in Sql server using SSDT. Is there any way that I could do in  one Step.   Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can just load text directly into excel without a SQL Server table. If you just sat down and opened the tool you'd probably work it out in five minutes

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. I tried but it i s asking to load data from Sql Command, Table or View.   But my input(Source) is flat file.

Comment: The dialogs should look something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-flat-file-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am understanding your question correctly, it is possible to use the import data wizard in SSMS to convert a text file to an excel file.  You can save the wizard as an SSIS package also if you need to do the conversion programatically.

1. right click on any database in your server, hover over 'tasks' and select 'import data...'
2. in 'data source' drop down, select 'flat file source'. click next.
3. browse to the file you want to import.  you can preview your flat file from here to make sure its rows and columns have been detected correctly. click next.
4. in 'destination' drop down, select 'microsoft excel'.  browse to the destination folder and name your file. click next.
5. here you can rename columns and preview the end result. click next.
6. map your data types and determine if you want the package to fail if you encounter an error. click next.
7. here you can choose to save as an SSIS package or just run one time. you can now click through the rest depending on your choice to finish the sequence.

This is a very brief overview.  for more detailed information, you can go here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried what all the steps you have provided. What it does is it added a Table in my database using Text document.    What I need is to convert Text file into Excel Sheet using SSDT.

Comment: i was able to do it successfully in my testing.  did you choose excel as the destination (step 4)?  when you run the wizard, you are basically using SSIS to create an ETL package.  it is not necessary to put the data into a table first.  There is no reason to open SSDT in Visual Studio since you would just be making the same package in SSIS.  If you want to use the package on a schedule, you can put it in your integration services catalogs on SSMS and run it from a SQL Server Agent job.  Try this: [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/125585/)

Comment: I have chosen source as flat file and destination as excel. I am getting following error :"Validation error. Data Flow Task: Data Flow Task: Column "COLUMN_1" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

Comment: HI @vishal.  sorry for the delayed response.  if you have not already solved this problem, i would try converting the data type in in the incoming txt file to unicode.  on the page where you choose your flat file, go to advanced > column > data type and choose unicode string.  this _should_ solve your issue.